# Conditionally logging into two different indexes on kibana - nest js

Tags: elasticsearch, nestjs, winston

I have a nest js application, that uses the following code to instantiate the application logger:

```js
const logger = WinstonModule.createLogger(winstonConfig);
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, new FastifyAdapter({ logger: true }), {
    logger,
});
```

So i can configurate to log to multiple indexes on elastic, but always logging everything to all indexes.

And i found a not so fancy way to log into different indexes according to the receveid log payload.

**But my question is: Is there a nest js opined way to create a condition to log to X indexes but not log to Y indexes in Z controllers/modules?**

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable above the app creation with an empty state
and then assign the value on your logging option based on your condition:

```
let logger 

if(x>y)logger= //what ever you want
else logger = //what ever you want
```

Finally, assign the logger to the logger variable.